# JQuery changing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I would like to adapt the initial page of my mvc 5 web site (bootstrap template) after the user has logged on. After the login a new  section will appear on the main page and I would like to change the class of all the other  tags in order to fit better the content of the home page.
Here is the code I've added to my page:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: lightblue">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: auto"><img src="~/Images/aaaa.png" /></td>
            <td style="width: 5%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" valign="bottom"><h1>Title</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="left"><p class="lead">Description</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div id="div1" class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Menu1</h2>
        <p>
            BLA BLA BLA
        </p>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("Leggi >>>", "Action1", "Controller1", new { }, new { target = "_self" })</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Menu2</h2>
        <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("Leggi >>>", "Action2", "Controller2", new { }, new { target = "_self" })</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Menu 3</h2>
        <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("Leggi >>>", "Action3", "Controller3", new { }, new { target = "_self" })</p>
    </div>
    @{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <div id="div4" class="col-md-3">
            <h2>Menu 4</h2>
            <p>BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
            <p>Leggi >>></p>
        </div>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") 
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".col-mod-4").removeClass("col-mod-4").addClass("col-mod-3");
            });
        </script>
        }
    }
</div>
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work. The class applied to  objects is not changed.
What am I doing wrong? Please, someone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `class` in `jQuery` that is not present in html code. In html you have `col-md-`4 for instance `<div id="div1" class="col-md-4">` instead of `col-mod-4` which you are looking in jquery code. Check what class you have in `css` and change the *html/css* accordingly. I assume you have `col-md-3` instead of `col-mod-3`

*Change*

```
$(".col-mod-4").removeClass("col-mod-4").addClass("col-mod-3");
```

*To*

```
$(".col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-4").addClass("col-md-3");
```

Comment: Really sorry for the waste of time in answering my stupid question!!! I am blind!!!! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may also try with following:

```
$(".oldclass").attr('class','').addClass("newclass");
```